# In Flask which arg overrides the other in request.values? (GET or POST)

Tags: python, flask

I'm unsure which values (GET or POST) take precedence in Flask's `request.values` combined dictionary.

Example:

```
@app.route('test', methods=['GET','POST'])
def test_url():
a = request.values.get(a)
# URL call has 'a' as GET parameter set to 'one'
# URL call also has 'a' as POST parameter set to 'two'
# which will my variable a contain if I call it as shown above?
print(a)
```

I would like to know that for the documentation of my Flask application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flask's `Request` class is a subclass of werkzeug's `Request`.

As can be [seen in werkzeug source code](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L545), `values` is a `CombinedMultiDict` of `args` (GET parameters) and `form` (POST parameters), in that order.

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/datastructures.py#L1416) of `CombinedMultiDict`, its `__getitem__` and `get` methods try to obtain the keys from the underlying dicts in the same order as specified during construction.

So, for `Request.values` it will return value from GET if it exists, otherwise the value from POST.

Answer (score 1):

It will return the value from the GET.